# Search in python list of dict

Tags: python

I have a list (l) of dictionaries `{"id": id, "class": class, "parameter": parameter}`. I have to do this,

```
for each value of class:
    parameter = getParameter(class) //we can get different parameter for same class
    if {"class":class, "parameter":parameter} not in l:
         increment id and do l.append({"id": id, "class": class, "parameter": parameter})
```

Here dict in list has 3 keys, where as i have to search in list with 2 keys. How can i validate 'if' condition?

Comment: `id` and `class` are reserved words. Don't use them for variable names.

Comment: thanks, i used those words only for representation. actual code is  free from reserved words

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly your problem is deciding if there is already an entry with the given values for `class` and `parameter`? You will have to write an expression that searches the list for you, like this:

```
def search_list(thedict, thelist):
    return any(x["class"] == thedict["class"]
               and x["parameter"] == thedict["parameter"]
               for x in thelist)
```

The function returns True if an entry is found. Call it like this:

```
if not search_list({"class": class, "parameter": parameter}, l):
    #the item was not found - do stuff
```

Comment: 'any' is life saver. it is new to me.

Answer (score 3):

```
if not any(d['attr1'] == val1 and d['attr2'] == val2 for d in l):
```

tests whether there is not dict `d` in list `l` with its `attr1` equal to `val1` and `attr2` equal to `val2`.

The advantage is that it stops the iteration as soon as match is found.

Answer (score 0):

```
if {"class":class, "parameter":parameter} not in [{'class':d['class'], 'parameter':d['parameter']} for d in l]:
```

You'll probably not want to calculate the list every time the condition is checked, do that outside of the loop.

Comment: Using a list comprehension seems wasteful when you can just evaluate this lazily with a generator. As the list changes (values that are not found get appended), you cannot calculate it once...

Answer (score 0):

I think with set comparison, you can get rid of that:

```
>>> d1 = {"id": 1, "class": 3, "parameter": 4}
>>> d2 = {"id": 1, "class": 3}
>>> set(d2.items()) < set(d1.items())
True
>>>
```